Formatting my writing
I'm having trouble keeping tense or even knowing which one to stick to. Both seem to work but I'm not sure which sounds better or flows more. Also, I think too much about how to structure dialogue. If anyone has advice please help!

Tense
Stories can be written in both past and present tense. Traditionally novels were written in the past tense and most novels today are still written in past tense. Only in Young Adult fiction (for readers 12 to 18), recently most stories have been written in present tense.
Present tense seems more immediate to some readers (as if the events are happening now and to them), but most readers find past tense more natural and experience those stories just as intensely.
Mostly it is a matter of preference. Decide for one tense and stick to it.
Dialogue
Whenever the speaker changes, insert a paragraph break. The change in speaker is called "turn-taking". Every turn gets its own paragraph.
You can make it clear who is speaking by adding "he said" or "she shouted". You can also make it clear by describing an action of the speaker in the same paragraph, e.g.:

"Would you like some more?" John pushed the box of icecream towards Joan.
Joan nodded. "Thank you."

Without "John said" or "Joan said" it is clear that John asks the question and Joan thanks him.

Start with those basics and see how it works.
Also, read some novels and see how those writers do it. What tenses do they use? How does each tense feel to you? Is that the feeling you want to evoke with your writing? How do they format dialogue? Do you understand who is speaking? How? Do you want to do it like that?

"Present tense seems more immediate to some readers (as if the events are happening now and to them), but most readers find past tense more natural and experience those stories just as intensely."  Hmmm.  Thinking about the novels I own (and others I've read,) it seems to me that they are all told in present tense.  Even events that happen in the past (told in flashbacks) are told in present tense.

@JRE Statistics clearly show that most novels are still written in the past tense. E.g. "Out of 114 novels shortlisted for the Man Booker Prize in 2000–2018, 31 novels (27.2%) are written in the present tense." (https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/full/10.1177/0963947019868894)

That paper is interesting.  It appears that I've been reading non-traditional novels for going on 50 years.  I am hard pressed to think of a single novel I have enjoyed that was told entirely in past tense as that paper implies is the norm.  The closest is To Kill a Mockingbird, and it seems to me that while it has part tense passages most of the story is told in present tense.

I say this with all the respect I can give. It's going to take time but you will need to read more.
10 pages a day, then 20, then 30, then 40. You should aim for a minimum of 200 pages a week every week for the rest of your life.
You need to strengthen your ability to understand written English and emulate what you're reading. Do not read fan-fic and self-published works. They're interferring with our ability to understand written communication; written works published for the world to read MUST go through an editor.
